# Reading a 10-byte buffer out of a PROGMEM string stored in a string table

Tags: string, progmem, memory

I'm storing a large snippet of text in three separate PROGMEM char arrays:

```
const char script1[] PROGMEM = "....";
const char script2[] PROGMEM = "....";
const char script3[] PROGMEM = "....";
```

The first two are 32766 characters, and the last one is 23867 characters (the whole string is 89400 characters in total). I store these in PROGMEM on an Arduino Mega 2560 (which then uses about 90K of 256K of available program memory).

I stored these three strings in a table, together with their lengths:

```
const int TABLE_SIZE = 3;
const char * const scriptTable[] PROGMEM = 
{   
  script1,
  script2,
  script3
};

const int scriptLengths[] {32767, 32767, 23867};
```

I have some issues trying to chunk up the string into 10-byte buffers, and processng it that way. I want to iterate through the table, process the first part in 10-byte chunks first, then move on to the second part, and finally the last part.

For a single string (`code`), the following works fine:

```
const char code[] PROGMEM = "....";

// Chunk up large code string in PROGMEM.
const int CHUNKSIZE = 10; // CHUNKSIZE *must* be an even number!!
char workingSpace[CHUNKSIZE + 1];
int baseIndex = 0;

while (baseIndex < sizeof(code)) {
    int chunk;
    if (baseIndex + CHUNKSIZE > sizeof(code)) {
        chunk = sizeof(code) - baseIndex;
        }
        else {
          chunk = CHUNKSIZE;
        }
        memcpy_PF(workingSpace, ((uint_farptr_t)code) + baseIndex, chunk);
        workingSpace[chunk] = '\0';

        // for debugging
        Serial.print("#");
        Serial.print(baseIndex);
        Serial.print("– Got a chunk [");
        Serial.print(workingSpace);
        Serial.println("]");        

        baseIndex += CHUNKSIZE;
```

However, I'm having some difficulties doing the memcpy_PF call using the table.

```
int tableIndex = 0;
// for each of the three script strings
for (tableIndex = 0; tableIndex < TABLE_SIZE; tableIndex++) {         
    // Chunk up large script strings in PROGMEM.
    const int CHUNKSIZE = 10; // CHUNKSIZE *must* be an even number!!
    char workingSpace[CHUNKSIZE + 1];
    int baseIndex = 0;

    // we can only use sizeof if it's a static var.
    // strlen should only be calculated once, expensive operation (loop until we encounter '\0').
    // now stored statically in scriptLengths table.
    Serial.println("tableIndex: ");
    Serial.println(tableIndex);     
    int strLength = scriptLengths[tableIndex];
    Serial.print("length script string: ");
    Serial.println(strLength);

    while (baseIndex < strLength) {
        int chunk;
        if (baseIndex + CHUNKSIZE > strLength) {
          chunk = strLength - baseIndex;
        }
        else {
          chunk = CHUNKSIZE;
        }
        // do memcpy_PF call here
```

I have tried several options here, mostly having difficulties with the second parameter (how to address the string stored in the table, and increase its indexing parameter). I read that the way to get a string out of a string table is to use pgm_read_word. However, with both of these below, I either get gibberish in the buffer string, or it seems to start in an incorrect location in the string.

```
memcpy_PF(workingSpace, ((uint_farptr_t) &scriptTable[tableIndex][baseIndex]), chunk);
memcpy_PF(workingSpace, ((uint_farptr_t) (char*)pgm_read_word(&(scriptTable[tableIndex])) + baseIndex), chunk);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need to fix is this:

```
/home/nick/Arduino/Large_Progmem_test/Large_Progmem_test.ino: In function 'foo()':
/home/nick/Arduino/Large_Progmem_test/Large_Progmem_test.ino:42:27: warning: iteration 3276 invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]
     baseIndex += CHUNKSIZE;
```

You are adding 10 to 32760 hoping to be >= `sizeof(code)` however now `baseIndex` will become negative as an int goes from -32768 to +32767.

---

There were some interesting subtleties to getting this working. :)

One of your major problems is this:

```
const char * const scriptTable[] PROGMEM =
```

That will give you 2-byte pointers (const char *) which will not be large enough to index into 89400 characters.

So you need to have an array of 4-byte pointers like this:

```
uint_farptr_t  scriptTable [TABLE_SIZE] =
```

However you can't just initialize those like you tried to. That has to be done procedurally with a macro that pulls in the full address. My working code is below:

```c++
#include "code.cpp"

const int TABLE_SIZE = 3;
uint_farptr_t  scriptTable [TABLE_SIZE];  // values calculated at runtime
const int scriptLengths[TABLE_SIZE] 
  {
  sizeof (script1), 
  sizeof (script2), 
  sizeof (script3)
  };

void foo ()
{
  // for each of the three script strings
  for (byte tableIndex = 0; tableIndex < TABLE_SIZE; tableIndex++) 
    {
    // Chunk up large script strings in PROGMEM.
    const int CHUNKSIZE = 10; // CHUNKSIZE *must* be an even number!!
    char workingSpace[CHUNKSIZE + 1];
    long baseIndex = 0;

    Serial.println ("----------------");
    Serial.print("tableIndex: ");
    Serial.println(tableIndex);
    long strLength = scriptLengths[tableIndex];
    Serial.print("length script string: ");
    Serial.println(strLength);

    while (baseIndex < strLength) {
      int chunk;
      if (baseIndex + CHUNKSIZE > strLength) {
        chunk = strLength - baseIndex;
      }
      else {
        chunk = CHUNKSIZE;
      }
      memcpy_PF(workingSpace, scriptTable [tableIndex] + baseIndex, chunk);
      workingSpace[chunk] = '\0';

      // for debugging
      Serial.print("#");
      Serial.print(baseIndex);
      Serial.print("- Got a chunk [");
      Serial.print(workingSpace);
      Serial.println("]");
      delay (50);
      baseIndex += CHUNKSIZE;
    } // end of while
  } // end of for
} // end of foo


void setup() 
{
  // get proper pointers to the various pieces of progmem
  scriptTable [0] = pgm_get_far_address (script1);
  scriptTable [1] = pgm_get_far_address (script2);
  scriptTable [2] = pgm_get_far_address (script3);

  Serial.begin (115200);
  foo ();
}

void loop() 
{
}
```

The file "code.cpp" just has the actual data in it (generated at http://www.lipsum.com).

As in:

```c++
#include <Arduino.h>

const char script1[] PROGMEM =  { 

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  ... " };

const char script2[] PROGMEM =  { 

"Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent aliquet accumsan arcu,  ... " };

const char script3[] PROGMEM =  { 

"Ut neque dolor, condimentum ut odio iaculis,  ... " };
```

Output:

```
----------------
tableIndex: 0
length script string: 32767
#0- Got a chunk [Lorem ipsu]
#10- Got a chunk [m dolor si]
#20- Got a chunk [t amet, co]
#30- Got a chunk [nsectetur ]
#40- Got a chunk [adipiscing]
#50- Got a chunk [ elit. Pro]
#60- Got a chunk [in sit ame]
#70- Got a chunk [t purus cu]
#80- Got a chunk [rsus, dict]
#90- Got a chunk [um magna q]
#100- Got a chunk [uis, place]
#110- Got a chunk [rat dui. I]
#120- Got a chunk [nteger ali]

...

#32700- Got a chunk [, eget tem]
#32710- Got a chunk [por dui te]
#32720- Got a chunk [mpor a. Do]
#32730- Got a chunk [nec malesu]
#32740- Got a chunk [ada mi et ]
#32750- Got a chunk [dolor cras]
#32760- Got a chunk [ amet.]
----------------
tableIndex: 1
length script string: 32767
#0- Got a chunk [Aliquam er]
#10- Got a chunk [at volutpa]
#20- Got a chunk [t. Praesen]
#30- Got a chunk [t aliquet ]
```

It successfully transitioned from the first array to the second one.

Comment: Good point, I missed that, thanks! Probably best to limit the size of script1,script2,script3, etc. to avoid overflows (e.g., to 30.000)?

Comment: Or use a `long` as an index.

Comment: Right, thanks! Any thoughts on the memcpy?

Comment: Maybe the avr-gcc compiler can not handle a PROGMEM section beyond 64kbytes. With a test sketch I am able to declare a lot of data (150kbytes), but the pointers in the Table[] stay 16-bit. They should be forced to 32-bit, but I don't know how. Even then, the memcpy_PF might not read beyond the first 64kbytes of the PROGMEM segment. So far I can't even read script3 directly with a function (when it is at the end of 150kbytes data).

Comment: See my amended answer.

Comment: I have tried a few things, and it it possible to create a 32-bit list of pointers with "const uint_farptr_t Table[] PROGMEM = ", but filling them during initialiazation will not fill them with the proper 32-bit addresses. I can't find another way to make it work than the workaround by Nick Gammon. The memcpy_PF() can retrieve data from PROGMEM that is beyond the 64kbytes border. It is the table that causes the problem. Also sizeof() and declaring too much data in a single array will cause trouble beyond the 64kbytes border, sometimes there is not even a compiler warning.

Comment: Thanks Nick and Jot! Nick's version is the solution we used eventually, and it seems to work. Particularly `pgm_get_far_address` seemed to be the missing puzzle piece. When reading data byte by byte from the strings in the table, it's also important to use `pgm_read_byte_far()` (vs. `pgm_read_byte()`). 

As you mentioned Jot, there is an open Arduino bug where built-in macros stop working once you go beyond 64K: see http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=455577.0 & https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/2226 We have reduced our strings to 40K in total to avoid that.